# Find the volume by revolution of the integral Mathematics

Tags: integration, solid-of-revolution

If we have the surface $S$ delimited $Y$ and the following functions, what is the volume found by the revolution of the surface $S$ around the $Y$ axis.

$f(x)= (x- 5)^2$

$g(x)= x^2+ x+ 3$

We have found that $(0, 25) (2, 9)$ lie on the graph of $f$ and $(0, 3) (2, 9)$ lie on the graph of $g.$

I found my answer to be $\frac{88\pi}{3},$ but it seems oddly small. Here is my "starting point" formula :

$\int_0^2 2\pi(-11x+ 22)x{\rm d}x$

$-11x+ 22$ is the result of $f(x)- g(x)$

Can you tell me if I have the right result ? Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: For the region you posted later, your answer of $\frac{88 \pi}{3}$ is absolutely correct.

Comment: @MathLover Thank you so much for your help. I will keep what you wrote in mind for my exams :P If you want to post a comment so I can accept it as an answer, go on :)

Comment: No not necessary. Good work!